# Derivative of cumulative sum function

Tags: calculus, differential

A cumulative sum is a sequence of partial sums:

Applying a cumulative sum to $\{a, b, c, d\}$ gives $\{a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d\}$.

A more formal notation, the cumulative sum function takes an $N$-dimensional vector and produces another $N$-dimensional vector:

$C(a) : \begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\a_N\end{bmatrix}  \xrightarrow{}  \begin{bmatrix}C_1 \\\vdots\\C_N\end{bmatrix}$

For example:

$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\4\\5\end{bmatrix}  \xrightarrow{}  \begin{bmatrix}1 \\3\\7\\12\\\end{bmatrix}$

The per-element formula is:

$C_N = \sum_{j=1}^N a_j$

Calculating the partial derivatives with respect to $a_i$ when $i = j$ and $i \ne j$:

$i = j$:

$\frac{\partial( \sum_{j=1}^N a_j)}{\partial a_i} =  \sum_{j=1}^N 1$

and $i \ne j$:

$\frac{\partial( \sum_{j=1}^N a_j)}{\partial a_i} =  \sum_{j=1}^N 0$

Does this look correct?

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange community! Great question! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site will help you get the most of your time here.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial C_N}{\partial a_i}=\frac{\partial C_N}{\partial a_j}=1$ if $C_N=a_1+\cdots+a_N$ and $i,j\in\{1,2,\cdots N\}$ for both $i=j$ and $i\neq j$.

$\frac{\partial C_N}{\partial a_i}=0$ if $i\notin\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$

Comment: Thanks Lee. I'm not so sure of it being 1 in all cases. Say $g_i$ = $a_j$, then the derivative of $g_i$ with respect to $a_j$ is 1 only if i = j, because that's the only time $g_i$ has $a_j$ in it. By the way, I'm modeling this after a similar derivation of the softmax function found at: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/